With introduction of React 19, how would you implement a refetch on some value change
The React 19 will introduce a use hook, which will allow us to avoid all the useEffects with state setting, but what if we want to refetch the same value on some state change, button click?
For example
const [joke, setJoke] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [shouldRefetch, setShouldRefetch]= useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchJoke = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random');
            const data = await res.json();
            setJoke(data);
            setLoading(false);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };
    fetchJoke();
}, [shouldRefetch]);

This is a dumb approach to do refetching which I am aware of, it's just for demo, but we could on a click of a button change the state and trigger a refetch
const JokeItem = () => {
    const joke = use(apiCall());
    return (
        <div className="bg-blue-50 shadow-md p-4 my-6 rounded-lg">
            <h2 className="text-xl font-bold">{joke.value}</h2>
        </div>
    );
};

And this is what React 19 brings us, how do we trigger a refetch in this case?
So far only thing that comes to mind is forcing a re-render, or calling it initially and setting it in useState then making a handler that does the refetch.

Could you not just call apiCall in an event handler directly if you want it called in response to a UI event like a button being clicked? React hooks, like useEffect, allow you couple asynchronous logic to the React component lifecycle. I think your question is too broad or unclear. Can you [edit] to clarify?

Note also that it's an anti-pattern to use a "shouldRefetch" state that is updated by a UI event just to trigger the effect to trigger the fetching... just trigger the fetching in the UI event handler. It's much simpler this way.

The context of the question is about use() from React 19. He wouldn't be able to call use() in the event handler (I think, it's not allowed -- though ready to be wrong). Calling apiCall directly in the handler without use goes against the questions aims which is to work with use()/suspense. He does acknowledge the shouldRefetch is suboptimal but its mostly inconsequential to what hes asking I think.

It's clear the question is about the experimental use hook, but I'm trying to point out the use case OP uses as an example is a poor choice as it'd be a react anti-pattern either way. I don't think it is helpful to answer based on an incorrect premise.

Yeh, I think its a bad example just to try to quickly get to the point. Even though bad, it does illustrate a (less than ideal) situation where you (whilst knowingly self-flagellating ) want to "control" the promise based on some outside action. The core "problem" exists if doing it properly with a refresh handler as the question itself is coming from mentally conflating use() with state management, which is its own thing. I beleive the answer is applicable to the premise regardless of how the refresh control flow is impl'ed.

With use you still need to manage the promise itself, probably in state. use is about providing an ergonomic way to hook into Suspense by way of working with promises directly, and not about fundamentally replacing state management. It does of course make it easier though (no more tracking loading states).
The JokeItem example provided probably does not achieve what you want since every time the promise resolves, the component will re-render and apiCall() would be called again which presumably would give a new unresolved promise. I.e. it would be in a waterfall loop.
A better representative example is this:
import { use, useState, Suspense } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [apiCallPromise, setApiCallPromise] = useState(() => apiCall());
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={"loading..."}>
      <JokeItem
        apiCallPromise={apiCallPromise}
        onRefreshClick={() => setApiCallPromise(apiCall())}
      />
    </Suspense>
  );
}

const apiCall = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({ value: "helo" });
    }, 1000);
  });
};

const JokeItem = ({ apiCallPromise, onRefreshClick }) => {
  const joke = use(apiCallPromise);

  return (
    <div className="bg-blue-50 shadow-md p-4 my-6 rounded-lg">
      <h2 className="text-xl font-bold">{joke.value}</h2>
      <button onClick={onRefreshClick}>Refresh</button>
    </div>
  );
};


This results in an infinite loop

Ive edited with a working example. Here is the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/green-wildflower-6tx8f2
